# Did Phinehas lose the Divine Spirit?

Tags: talmud-gemara

I was reading an article that mentioned Phinehas, it said he lost the divine spirit, is there a reason for this?

Comment: I was learning Shoftim recently and I remember reading in a footnote on the bottom that at a certain period of time during Shoftim (I forgot which one, could’ve been multiple though), Bnei Yisroel were sinning and Phineas who was still alive didn’t interfere and try to bring them back on the derech. So perhaps because of his failing to lead the nation during the Shoftim period did he lose his divine spirit

Comment: Also, during Yiftach’s time, Yiftach had that whole bad situation where he made a vow and it ended up being that he had to kill his daughter (supposedly). But in any case, the Gemara tells us that Pinchas could have annulled Yiftach’s vow because Pinchas was the head of the court, and the vow was faulty. But they were both stubborn- Yiftach felt Pinchas should come to him to annul it because Yiftach was the great Shofet of the time. Pinchas felt the opposite- come to me because I’m so great. So because of this stubbornness Yiftach’s daughter died, and perhaps that’s why Pinchas lost his spirit

Comment: Pinchas shows up in Shoftim 20:24 @CuriousYid . Depending on how you view the chronology of the book of Shoftim, he could have been alive all the way through all those troubles.

Comment: @DoubleAA always wondered about that because Shoftim spans several hundred years, plus the 28 years of the book of Joshua, plus however long Pinchas was alive in the Torah, he would be so old. First of all is this possible (since most people at those times died at most in the 100’s like Moshe) and secondly why would Pinchas specifically merit to live such a long life

Comment: @CuriousYid According to opinion that Pinchas is Eliyahu, he essentially lived forever.  Even according to other opinion, he merited a long life as a result of G-d's promise to him in the beginning of Parshas Pinchas, for saving the Jewish people.

Comment: @N.T. what sources say Pinchas is Eliyahu? Never heard that before

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%A1%20%D7%96%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=chronological&svar=1&ssort=relevance